# Resizing Behaviour of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, awt

I have a JFrame and I would like to change its resizing behaviour.
More specifically, when I drag the JFrame to the right I want it to resize as if I was dragging it from the diagonal. So when I drag it to the right, the default behavior is that only the width increases and when I drag it from the diagonal both the width and the height increase. How can I override the behaviour so that when dragging to the right behaves as I was dragging it from the diagonal.

Many thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a `ComponentListener` to the JFrame and then manually resize the height to the same proportion as the width in the `componentResized` method.

Don't know if it is the best way, but that would work.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you would want to do is make a component listener or a component adapter. When the frame is moved you could increase the size both vertically or horizontal depending on which direction the frame moved.